# Multiple Project in Symfony2 Framework

Tags: symfony

Symfony2 framework is a bundle. Any additional features from third-party are also bundle. So, every Symfony2 project needs bundle, and as it happens, several projects will use some similar bundles from third-party.

To explain my question, I made this example.
I have a Symfony2 Framework in "sf2" folder.
I have 3 website projects, and I decided to use Symfony2 framework to build them.
In my current condition, I copy the "sf2" folder into 3 more folders: sf2-web1, sf2-web2, sf2-web3.
In each sf2* folder, there maybe some similar bundles used in them.

The question is, is it possible to develop 3 project in only one Symfony2 Framework Folder?
and how to do it?

Comment: A symfony project is only the app and web folder, the src folder with your source code and a composer.json file. I guess your app folder will change depending on the project as well as the web folder. So what do you want to share?

Comment: You should add you vendors as dependencies in your composer.json (or deps file if you are using symfony2.0.X). Your src folder is only for your application specific bundles (you could have a website bundle and a backoffice bundle for administration for example).

Comment: Example: I have src/Acme/BlogBundle for www.acme-blog.local and src/Emca/ForumBundle for www.emca-forum.local. Is it possible to do that in only one Symfony2 Framework?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its possible. I would use the next directory stucture in your case:

```
/projects
    1stProject
        app         
        src         
        web
        ..
    2ndProject
        app
        src
        web
        ...
    ..
    vendor          <- Core and third-party bundles
```

Every project uses same vendors, symfony version and third-party bundles.

If ever you need to separate one of these projects just copy vendor folder to project folder and change path to vendors in autoload.php

Comment: Can we make multiple project only in the src folder? I mean that we only use multiple Vendor name without duplicate any folder?

Comment: As you have different app folders (and I guess different composer files) you may run into problems with different versions of one software.